# Saved Bitmap Instance not Saving to Device Media

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-manifest

When i Running time The program throw an excpetion about the given path is not available.
This is My Main Activity Class Implementation

The Android framework includes support for various cameras and camera features available on devices, allowing you to capture pictures and videos in your applications. This document discusses a quick, simple approach to image and video capture and outlines an advanced approach for creating custom camera experiences for your users.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1023;
        ImageView mImageView;
        Button mButton;
        Button save;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.captureView);
            mButton  =(Button)findViewById(R.id.captureBtn);
            save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
            mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent camIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(camIntent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
            });

            save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                }
            });

        }


    private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/DCIM/");
        myDir.mkdir();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE){
            Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
             SaveImage(bm);
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
    }
}
```

This is Exception i got in Run time

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Image-8834.jpg (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
                  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:287)
                  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:223)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
                  at com.project.melan.cameraapp.MainActivity.SaveImage(MainActivity.java:62)
                  at com.project.melan.cameraapp.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:79)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7290)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4267)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4315)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1647)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Application terminated.
```

Thank you if anyone help to solve this exception.

Comment: you have `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Image-8834.jpg (Permission denied)` saying that you dont have the write permission to that file

Comment: I used <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in android maifest file

Comment: what is the output of `adb shell ls -l /storage/emulated/0/DCIM` and ``adb shell ls -ld /storage/emulated/0/DCIM`` commands?

Comment: 10/12 10:44:53: Launching app
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of /home/melan/Desktop/CameraAPP/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop com.project.melan.cameraapp
$ adb shell am start -n "com.project.melan.cameraapp/com.project.melan.cameraapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Wai

Comment: i am not talking about `adb shell am start`, i am talking about `adb shell ls`

Comment: total 28
drwxrwx--x 2 root sdcard_rw  4096 2018-08-23 21:55 1Videoshow
drwxrwx--x 8 root sdcard_rw  4096 2018-08-23 22:12 AndroVid
drwxrwx--x 2 root sdcard_rw 16384 2018-10-10 11:20 Camera
drwxrwx--x 2 root sdcard_rw  4096 2018-10-08 10:03 Facebook

Comment: drwxrwx--x 7 root sdcard_rw 4096 2018-08-23 22:12 /storage/emulated/0/DCIM

Comment: so you have `drwxrwx--x`, the owner is `root`, group is `sdcard_rw`, for more see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes